# Reading/writing a list of nested dictionaries to/from a CSV file (Python)

Tags: python

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
data  =[
{'key_1': { 'calc1': 42, 'calc2': 3.142 } },
{'key_2': { 'calc1': 123.4, 'calc2': 1.414 } },
{'key_3': { 'calc1': 2.718, 'calc2': 0.577 } }
]
```

I want to be able to save/and load the data into a CSV file with the following format

```
key,    calc1,   calc2   <- header
key_1,  42,      3.142   <- data rows
key_2,  123.4,   1.414
key_3,  2.718,   0.577
```

What's the 'Pythonic' way to read/save this data structure to/from a CSV file like the one above?

Comment: Out of interest, why would you use a list of n length 1 dicts of dicts, instead of a single length n dict of dicts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that it would be possible to use `csv` module, due to all the idiosyncrasies in your requirements and the structure, but you could do it quite easily writing it manually:

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(['key', 'calc1', 'calc2']) + '\n')
    f.writelines('{},{},{}'.format(k, *v.values()) + '\n' for l in data for k,v in l.items())
```

Comment: @silentghost: +1 for the nice and short snippet. I am sure what I would have come up with, would have been a lot more verbose. However, with the succinctness, comes a level of "wtf-ness". Could you please explain the third line - the parameters being passed to writelines()?  thanks.

Comment: perhaps a note that that sorta formatting only works with Python versions of 2.6 onwards

Comment: it is just an iterator of string. Each formatted as a comma-separated list, because of nested-ness of your `data`, I had to iterate twice.

Comment: @silentghost: also, how can you be sure that the keys returned in l.items() will be correctly ordered (i.e. will be in the same column in the generated CSV file)?.

Comment: @Tshepang: there's nothing preventing you from changing it to the classical `%` formatting.

Comment: @morpheous: given the same key names, `dict.items()` returns value in a predictable order. You could of course modify this example to return values in the order you desire.

Comment: @SilentGhost: That's not the point. I was merely was a suggestion that in your answer, you should have indicated that the formatting was for versions 2.6 onwards.

Comment: @Tshepand: it's a formatting recommended in a current stable version of Python!

Comment: @SilentGhost: What is that predictable order? [TFM](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.items#dict.items) just says that the *same* dictionary will return keys in the same order, if the dictionary is not modified, but it doesn't say which order, or that that order will be the same as another different dictionary with the same keys.

Answer (score 6):

Just to show a version that does use the csv module:

```
from csv import DictWriter

data  =[
{'key_1': { 'calc1': 42, 'calc2': 3.142 } },
{'key_2': { 'calc1': 123.4, 'calc2': 1.414 } },
{'key_3': { 'calc1': 2.718, 'calc2': 0.577 } }
]

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, ['key', 'calc1', 'calc2'])
    writer.writerow(dict(zip(writer.fieldnames, writer.fieldnames))) # no automatic header :-(
    for i in data:
        key, values = i.items()[0] # each dict in data contains only one entry
        writer.writerow(dict(key=key, **values)) # first make a new dict merging the key and the values
```

Comment: You should be able to use `writer.writeheader()` to write out the header. (as of 2.7) :-)

Answer (score -1):

I feel the by far easiest approach is to transform the dictionary first into a pandas dataframe and from there very convenient into a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index') # it is either ‘columns’ or ‘index’ (simple transpose)
    df.to_csv('filepath/name.csv')
```

To load the file back into the dict form

```
df.to_csv('filepath/name.csv')
data_dict = df.to_dict()
```

For more complicated cases have a look into the pandas documentation
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html
and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html