# Python equivalent to R data frames

Tags: python, arrays, r

What is the Python equivalent to R's `read.csv()` function, and the `data.frame` it returns?

Is there a similar data structure in Python?

Comment: Did you look at the Python docs at all? There is a module dedicated to CSV.

Comment: The csv module is not a complete answer to the question, as it contains no equivalent datastructure.

Comment: Python has a the `csv` module to read .csv, but it doesn't have a native table type. You can use a list of lists, list of dicts, or any collection/collection, collection/iterator or iterator/collection type combo, or a third party's matrix type element like numpy/scipy's matrix. The ideal type will probably be application dependent.

Comment: The python library `pandas` enables `data.frame`-like capability

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195982/reading-writing-a-list-of-nested-dictionaries-to-from-a-csv-file-python for one of the options Nisan.H mentions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your have two elements in your question, (1) reading/writing CSV and (2) an equivalent data structure to the R `data.frame` that results from reading in a CSV-file.

For the first part, there is the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) in the standard library.

For the second part, the standard library is lacking a equivalent tabular data structure with the flexibility of the the R `data.frame`. You have two options, depending on the complexity of the operations you will be doing afterwards:

- A more lightweight option is [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/index.html). It contains functions for reading/writing CSV and basic manipulations, sub-setting, etc.
- A more comprehensive (perhaps overkill) solution is the [`DataFrame` data structure](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) in the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package. It has similar [read/write functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files) for tabular fileformats, but has [indexing/slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection), [manipulation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion), [built-in summary operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html), etc. simmilar to the the R `data.frame`.

Comment: I would only add that if you're a long time R user, you'll likely _really_, _really_ want a "complete" analogue to data frames, in which case pandas is very unlikely to be overkill.

Comment: Pandas is the best choice for data-frame-like functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at pandas.

Comment: +1 for Pandas.  It gives a very R like syntax (especially if you use data.table) that makes the transition much more gentle.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not enough to sate your hunger?

```
import StringIO
import csv


f = StringIO.StringIO("""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6""")

r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
print [x for x in r]
```

Gives:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```